# How to not have the mat-sidenav-content take up blank space on webpage

Tags: angular

I am creating a mat-sidenav-container to create a mobile menu view. I cannot display the full menu unless I set style="height: 80vh;" in the mat-sidenav-content tags. When I set it I get this blank white space on the webpage:

[image]

If I change the style to "style="height: 20vh;" and click on the icon menu, I cannot see all of the choices. I must scroll through them.

How may I display all of the menu choices after I click the menu icon and not have the white blank main content?

Below is the html code:

```
 <mat-sidenav-container>
      <mat-sidenav mode="push" #sidenav>
        <mat-nav-list>
    <!--These buttons are displayed on greater than xs view-->
    <a mat-list-item  *ngIf="!signedIn" routerLink="/auth" (click)="onSidenavClose()">
      <span class="nav-caption">Log in</span>
   </a>
   <a mat-list-item *ngIf="signedIn" routerLink="/demo" (click)="onSidenavClose()">
     <mat-icon>account_balance</mat-icon><span class="nav-caption">Demo</span></a>
     <a mat-list-item  *ngIf="!signedIn" routerLink="/auth" (click)="onSidenavClose()">
      <span class="nav-caption">Log in</span>
   </a>
   <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/contacts'"> Contacts </a>
   <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/create-contact'"> Create Contact </a>
   <a mat-list-item (click)="sidenav.toggle()" href="" mat-list-item>Close</a>

   </mat-nav-list>
      </mat-sidenav>
      <mat-sidenav-content>
        <div style="height: 30vh;">      
        </div>
      </mat-sidenav-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-side-nav-design) try this out

Comment: I did not want a   <mat-sidenav-content> element at all. I am using this as a nav bar for all pages. I guess I can add some mat-sidenave contents for the mobile display.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
<mat-sidenav-container style="height:'100vh'">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav class="slide-mobile-sidenav" style="height: 100vh;">
</mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: When I do not added <mat-sidenav-content style="height: 30vh;">          </mat-sidenav-content> after the mat-sidenav element I have no space to see the menu elements after clicking on the menu icon.